# what level of the factor comes first ggpredict

Tags: r

I am using the r package - ggeffects function ggpredict. When I run my model, it gives me a x value, this is the results of a main effect that is a factor with 2 levels, however, although the factor is named, it just says level 1 and 2. So I cannot determine whether the first level of the factor is 1, or the second level of the factor is 1. Any idea which level of the factor comes first?

When I look at the components of there is an attribute it says the order, but how do I access these attributes consistently? It seems to be that the order is changing depending on whether the level that first appears in the model.

Comment: It should be explicit: 1 is 1 and 2 is 2. However, `factor` variables could be tricky sometimes.  If you provide a reproducible sample and  code, others could help you check this.

Comment: So if I plot the object the name emerges reliably.

Comment: I should be careful here without seeing your data and code. I need to see the data and code to confirm this.